# Структуры c++ core dump

Tags: struct, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;

int count=0;

struct student{
    string name;
    int firstMark;
    int secondMark;
    int thirdMark;
    int middleMark;
};

void addStudent(vector<student*> base){
    string buffer;
    int buff;
    student st;
    base.push_back(&st);
    cout << "Enter student name\n";
    cin >> buffer;
    base[count]->name = buffer;
    cout << "Enter student first mark\n";
    cin >> buff;
    base[count]->firstMark = buff;
    cout << "Enter student second mark\n";
    cin >> buffer;
    base[count]->secondMark = buff;
    cout << "Enter student third mark\n";
    cin >> buffer;
    base[count]->thirdMark = buff;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    vector<student*> studentBase;
    int chose;
    bool contin = true;
    while(contin){
        cout << "***Welcome in Student DataBase***\n";
        cout << "Please chose what you want\n";
        cout <<"1.Add Student\n";
        cout <<"2.Show Student\n";
        cout <<"3.delete Student\n";
        cout <<"4.Exit\n";
        cin >> chose;
        //switch(chose){
            //case 1:
        //}
        addStudent(studentBase);
        cout << studentBase[0]->name;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

написал вот такой код, компилируется, но когда я ввожу последние данные - выпадает с core dump.

> Ошибка сегментирования (core dumped)

как можно это исправить?

Comment: У вас тут столько ошибок, что аж зашкаливает.

Добавление в вектор указателя на стековую переменную, которая умрёт после окончания процедуры — раз. Передача массива по значению, а не по ссылке — два. Обращение к элементу массива по индексу без проверки его длины — три. Наверняка ещё что-то есть.

Comment: > student st;

В С++ точно такое разрешено? (не `struct student`, а просто `student`)

Comment: "Добавление в вектор указателя на стековую переменную, которая умрёт после окончания процедуры" и как это исправить. это учебное задание, главное использовать стркуктуры, остальное не важно.

Comment: @Fike: В C++ — да.

Comment: @Володимир Гончаров:

    student st;

Объект `st` расположен в стеке. Внимание, вопрос: «Дорогие знатоки, что случится памятью, которую он использует, когда функция `addStudent` окончится?»

Comment: какая процедура в с++ вроде не принято использовать термин процедура поэтому я не могу понять про что вы говоритею

Comment: @Володимир Гончаров: не придирайтесь к терминам. Изменил комментарий, даже написал имя функции.

Comment: @Володимир Гончаров есть такой отладчик -- gdb. Он позволяет работать с core dump (если этот core dump сформирован -- см. ulimit). Это на случай следующих "выпаданий в кору"

Comment: что то я вообще  не пойму как делать сделал как советовал avp, но не пойму что делать теперь в функции get_student() ведь теперь элемент в вектор кладеться в main как к нему можно обратиться из функции?

Comment: решил, спасибо

Comment: например передать вектор по ссылке в get_student() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Володимир Гончаров](/users/8138/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/8138/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), коренным образом улучшить ситуацию позволит упрощение программы и более логичное разбиение ее не части.

Сделайте вместо функции

```
void addStudent(vector<student*> base);
```

функцию

```
student get_student();
```

вместо

```
vector<student*> studentBase;
```

напишите

```
vector<student> studentBase;
```

а в `main` для добавления нового студента просто пишите

```
 studentBase.push_back(get_student());
```

Соответственно, вместо оператора `->` используйте оператор `.`.

Ну, а ошибки ввода данных -- так ошибки-то Вы ведь все равно не обрабатываете.